# Can't compile nearcore project after last RocksDB version bump

Tags: nearprotocol

Here are the important parts of the error

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `librocksdb-sys v6.2.4`
Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `nearcore/target/debug/build/librocksdb-sys-9223f5cf5557dfe7/build-script-build` (exit code: 101)

--- stderr
rocksdb/include/rocksdb/c.h:65:10: fatal error: 'stdarg.h' file not found
rocksdb/include/rocksdb/c.h:65:10: fatal error: 'stdarg.h' file not found, err: true
thread 'main' panicked at 'unable to generate rocksdb bindings: ()', src/libcore/result.rs:1165:5
```

If I'm missing something (ie. `stdarg.h`), is there a way to just include it automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to install `llvm` and `clang`

Unfortunately there isn't a way to automatically check for and include this that I know of.

The Near team should update the relevant Dockerfile(s) and add something to [docs.nearprotocol.com](http://docs.nearprotocol.com/)

> to fix this error run:
>
> `apt install llvm clang`
>     ... or ...
>   `brew install llvm clang`

Comment: docs reference: https://docs.nearprotocol.com/docs/local-setup/running-testnet#compile-testnet-without-docker